# Vim find and replace multiple lines in whole project

Tags: search, vim, replace

I have code like this:

```py
        item = QStandardItem(self.list.icon, name)
        self.list.model.appendRow(item)
        self.list.model.sort(0)
```

And I want to replace it with this:

```py
        add_database(self.list, name)
```

And I want to do it in my whole project (i.e. its directory).
I use `fzf` and `ferret` vim plugins, can they help me somehow?

Comment: I see `self`, guess it is python codes. it won't be a good idea to do this "automatically". since once indentation was broken, your codes won't work any longer.

Comment: Well, yes, but I handle it smartly, the point is how do I replace a lot of lines? Does it even possible in vim? This example is python code but what if I need something like this, not in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open required files in vim with args command:

   args project_dir/**/*.py
2. Execute substitution on all opened files:

`argdo %s;\(\s*\)item = QStandardItem(self.list.icon, name)\n\1self.list.model.appendRow(item)\n\1self.list.model.sort(0);\1add_database(self.list, name);g`

It preserves indentation which is important in Python, as Kent noticed.

`\n` is new line symbol here.

`\1` is group recall.

See help topics for more info:

```
:h :args
:h :argdo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know all this commands, it just I couldn't construct proper regex.

Comment: It didn't work, it says: Illegal back reference, suggestions?

Comment: I figure out that you need to use this `^\(\s*\)item = QStandardItem(self.list.icon, name)\n\1self.list.model.appendRow(item)\n\1self.list.
model.sort(0)` regex, anyway thanks for idea! And don't forget to fix your answer so I could mark it as the right one.

Comment: Oh, sorry, copied wrong command from history, forgot leading backslash.

Comment: Ha, even more funny! I copied right command, but StackOverflow message editor could not apply "code block" to it by some reason. Leading spaces were useless, but manual surround with single quotes did the job. Also leading ^ in regex is not important, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ripgrep, you can do this from the commandline: `rg -l 'my_search' | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/my_search/my_new_value/'`

Or if you want an in-vim solution, this will also work: `:cfdo %s/my_search/replacement/gc` and `:cdo update` to update.